# Deleting a specified value from a selectbox

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

How can I go about dynamically deleting an option from a drop down (select) box? The value will need to be retrieved and then deleted manually.

i.e.

```
    [DROP DOWN BOX]
    Apples
    Oranges
    Pears
    Kiwis
    Mangos
    Strawberries
```

var option_to_delete = "Pears"

Some code to dynamically search through the select box options for "Pears", and if detected, remove it.

Expected result:

```
    [DROP DOWN BOX]
        Apples
        Oranges
        Kiwis
        Mangos
        Strawberries
```

No jQuery libaries please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will loop through the dropdown box and if one of the elements is equal to your variable `option_to_delete`.

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('ID_OF_DROPDOWN');
var option_to_delete = "Pears"

for (i=0;i<dropdown.length;  i++) {
   if (dropdown.options[i].value==option_to_delete) {
     dropdown.remove(i);
   }
}
```

I adapted some code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601791/298051

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the child nodes in the `<select>` and remove the child where the `innerText` or `value` that is equal to "Pears".

I have provided a jsfiddle of doing so: http://jsfiddle.net/pcb8q/

Answer (score 1):

You can structure your html like that

```
    <select id="fruits">
        <option value="apples">Apple</option>
        <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
        <option value="kiwis">Kiwis</option>
    </select>
```

Then in JS

```
    var selectBox = document.getElementById('#fruits');
    var options = selectBox.getElementsByTagName('option');
    var optionToDelete = 'apples';

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].value === optionToDelete) {
            selectBox.removeChild(options[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This works great too! So many ways to skin a cat!