# Chosen Select: append and remove items from a multiple select

Tags: javascript, select, jquery-chosen

**EDIT:**
I will explain my problem better:

I have a Select Multiple created with Jquery-plugin --> Chosen.
I create the Options inside the Select with Ajax+Php+MySQL and this:

```
$("#Enmarcado").append(array_items[x]); //inside a loop
[...]
$("#Enmarcado").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Now, with the Select created, I want validate which options you can select:

This is my select (html created by Ajax+Php+MySQL)

```
<select id="Enmarcado" name="Enmarcado" data-placeholder="Elije los acabados..." class="chosen-select" multiple="" onchange="validar_enmarcado();">
    <option selected="" value="-1">Sin Acabados</option>
    <option value="20">Kappa-fix 10mm (PVC)</option>
    <option value="19">Kappa-fix 5mm (PVC)</option>
    <option value="18">Laminado mate (75 micras producción)</option>
    <option value="17">Laminado brillo (75 micras producción)</option>
    <option value="16">Laminado mate (30-50 micras)</option>
    <option value="15">Laminado brillo (30-50 micras)</option>
    <option value="14">Plastificado brillo (125 micras)</option>
    <option value="13">Plastificado brillo (75 - 80 micras)</option>
    <option value="11">Adhesivado</option>
    <option value="7">Kappa-fix 10 mm (cartón pluma alta densidad)</option>
    <option value="6">Kappa-fix 5 mm (cartón pluma alta densidad)</option>
    <option value="5">Laminado Mate (proteccion uv)</option>
    <option value="4">Laminado Brillo (proteccion uv)</option>
    <option value="3">Aluminio</option>
    <option value="2">Bastidor 4 cm</option>
    <option value="1">Bastidor 2 cm</option>
    <option value="9">Dibond 3mm (sandwich aluminio + pvc)</option>
</select>
```

The first option is absolute: If you select it, it clears all other options.

```
<option selected="" value="-1">Sin Acabados</option>
```

But If I have this option selected, I want delete it, and leave the new selected option when I select another option:

```
<option selected="" value="-1">Sin Acabados</option> <!-- Selected yet -->
<option value="20">Kappa-fix 10mm (PVC)</option> <!-- I want select this, clearing value =-1 from the selected options. -->
```

My validation function:

**EDIT2:**

```
function validar_enmarcado(){
    var obj = document.getElementById ("Enmarcado");
    var enmarcado = new Array();

    var i = 0;
    var u = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var cont = 0;
    var opt1 = "";
    var opt2 = "";

    enmarcado = obj.selectedOptions;
    if(enmarcado.length>1){
        for (i=0; opt1=enmarcado[i];i++){
            for (u=i+1; opt2=enmarcado[u];u++){
                if(opt1.value == -1){
                    if(opt2.value >= 1){
                        $("#Enmarcado").chosen();
                        $("#Enmarcado").val(-1).trigger("chosen:updated");
                        jAlert("Si elige Sin Acabados, no puede haber acabados en la lista.","Error de Acabado");
                    }
                }
                if(opt1.value == 6 || opt1.value == 7 || opt1.value == 9 || opt1.value == 19 || opt1.value == 20){
                    if(opt2.value == 6 || opt2.value == 7 || opt2.value == 9 || opt2.value == 19 || opt2.value == 20){
                        jAlert("No puede elegir dos Soportes al mismo tiempo, elimino uno.","Error de Acabado");
                    }
                }
                if(opt1.value == 1 || opt1.value == 2){
                    if(opt2.value == 1 || opt2.value == 2){
                        jAlert("No puede elegir dos Bastidores al mismo tiempo, elimino uno.","Error de Acabado");
                    }
                }
                if(opt1.value == 4 || opt1.value == 5 || opt1.value == 13 || opt1.value == 14 || opt1.value == 15 || opt1.value == 16 || opt1.value == 17 || opt1.value == 18){
                    if(opt2.value == 4 || opt2.value == 5 || opt2.value == 13 || opt2.value == 14 || opt2.value == 15 || opt2.value == 16 || opt2.value == 17 || opt2.value == 18){
                        jAlert("No puede elegir dos Laminados o Plastificados al mismo tiempo, elimino uno.","Error de Acabado");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is:

```
<option selected="" value="-1">Sin Acabados</option>
```

This is the default option, and I want to remove it when I select other option. But I dont know how to do it, without removing the other validations.

I cannot get the last option selected from the list of $("#Enmarcado").selectedOptions[] because a multiple select always reorder the selected items with the $("#Enmarcado").options[] order.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT3:**

I just found a bit of code that give me the "selected option value":

```
$("#Enmarcado").chosen().change(function() {
    alert(+$(this).val());
});
```

But it sends me NaN when I select multiple options. Could anyone help to insert this in my validation function?

*Response to this:* delete the + before $(this).val() and it will send you an string with the selected values. But is not that I want: I need know WHICH option I just selected(or clicked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the solution](http://marcgrabanski.com/jquery-select-list-values/) by using Google today:

```
var foo = [];
$('#EnmarcadoChosen :selected').each(function(i, selected){
    foo[i] = $(selected).text(); // you can get the .value() too, and compare it.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as:  `$("#Enmarcado option[value='-1']").remove();`

But if the above doesn't work in your context, could you build on **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601691/remove-item-from-dropdown-list-on-page-load-no-jquery)** by VirtualTroll?  (If so, upvote his, too.)  In your case, that could look like:

```
for (i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
   if (obj.options[i].value=='-1') {
     obj.remove(i);
   }
}
```

And note a few gentler approaches, that might make it easier to turn the default back on, later: 
 
1: `$("#Enmarcado option[value='-1']").hide();` 
2: `$("#Enmarcado option[value='-1']").attr('disabled','disabled');`

**UPDATE:**

From your new comments below, it's now clear that you're not looking to "delete" or "remove" the option -- you're only looking to *clear*, or "unselect", the *selection* of the option.  Though I did not *know* an answer to that, I do think I *found* answers to that.  (Again, if this information works for you, please upvote their answers too.)

(1) Note **[Sudhir Kesharwani's solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191111/how-to-clear-the-select-boxes/21636570#21636570)**.  I think his code clears *all* selections... so, attempting a variation of his code, would this shorthand version work?:

```
$("#Enmarcado option[value='-1']").removeAttr("selected");
$("#Enmarcado").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

And (2), you might find the documentation useful.  In [Joseph Silber's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365212/how-do-i-reset-a-jquery-chosen-select-option-with-jquery/11365340#11365340), he refers to [the documentation here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), saying "(find the section titled **Updating Chosen Dynamically**)."  It explains that you have to trigger `chosen:updated` after any selection changes.

I hope that helps...

Comment: In my function validar_enmarcado() I can remove all options when I select the 1st option with:

`$("#Enmarcado").chosen(); //resets the select
 $("#Enmarcado").val(-1).trigger("chosen:updated"); //selects the 1st option`


but when I have the first option selected YET, I want to delete it when I select another option.

BUT I don't want to delete the options from obj.option[], I only want delete them from obj.selectedOptions[];

My problem aren't the commands, is the logarythm:

I can delete the options with a loop and `obj.selectedOptions[i].selected=false;`

Comment: @BarragánLouisenbairn So, is it that you want to **"unselect"** that value (the default), when other options are selected?

Comment: yes! that's it! But i don't want lose the other validation: 
1.- When I click in Default value, all other options are "unselected".

Comment: @BarragánLouisenbairn Did the above help?  If there are still issues, a you post them (replying here or appending a question edit), I'll be happy to see if I can help.  And... if I don't have answers, I'd be willing to put a small bounty on your question... if you still need that.

Comment: 1.- I edited the question a few days ago, but no one answer how to solve my problem correctly: how to know which element I just selected(clicked) in a select multiple.

2.- My solution: changing how my code works, avoiding the need of know which element the user just click in each iteraction. Or in other words: delete & bypass it. I won't tell how I bypass that need, is part of my algorythm. sorry, but cannot post more of the inner code of my app.

Comment: I understand not wanting to reveal too much, publicly.  Note: my answer edit, above, which gave a lot of new information, was *AFTER* your last question edit.  Did you try that?

Comment: mmm yes, you can use that code to delete the option, but... how can I know the difference between the case when I select the default option before I selected another option, and the case when I had the default option seleted yet, and I select another option? because the "selectedOptions" array is being reorderer always the options... (sorry if I don't know how to explain this very well)

Comment: `  for (i=0; opt1=enmarcado[i];i++){
   for (u=i+1; opt2=enmarcado[u];u++){
    if(opt1.value == -1){
     $("#Enmarcado").chosen();
     $("#Enmarcado").val(-1).trigger("chosen:updated");
     jAlert("Si elige Sin Acabados, no puede haber otros acabados en la lista. Quite esta opci&oacute;n si quiere hacer cambios.","Error de Acabado");
     return false;
    }
    else{
     $("#Enmarcado option[value='-1']").removeAttr("selected");
     $("#Enmarcado").trigger("chosen:updated");
    }`